# Three Imges load from three url and show in 3 picturebox

Tags: c#, image, url, picturebox

I am trying to request 3 images from 3 url and then try to show in three picturebox.But I am having problem in my code. Answers are greatly appreciated!

```
       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


           var request1 = WebRequest.Create("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f8/Schloss_Neuschwanstein_2013.jpg/300px-Schloss_Neuschwanstein_2013.jpg");
           var request2 = WebRequest.Create("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f8/Schloss_Neuschwanstein_2013.jpg/300px-Schloss_Neuschwanstein_2013.jpg");
          var request3 = WebRequest.Create("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f8/Schloss_Neuschwanstein_2013.jpg/300px-Schloss_Neuschwanstein_2013.jpg");




        using (var response1 = request1.GetResponse())
        using (var response2 = request2.GetResponse())
        using (var response3 = request2.GetResponse())


        using (var stream1 = response1.GetResponseStream())
        using (var stream2 = response2.GetResponseStream())
        using (var stream3 = response2.GetResponseStream())


        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Bitmap.FromStream(stream1);
            pictureBox2.Image = Bitmap.FromStream(stream2);
            pictureBox3.Image = Bitmap.FromStream(stream3);

          }

      }

   }
 }
```

Comment: What is actually the problem ?

Comment: @JohnLouieDelaCruz My coding is not running, whenever I try to run this , it become hang.

Comment: Please, add further details, such as a stacktrace ([by logging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42ste2f3%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)), show a way to reproduce the problem, show the expected result, as well as details on the classes used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Load("http://i.imgur.com/ZkWyBo5.jpg?2");
        pictureBox2.Load("http://i.imgur.com/ZkWyBo5.jpg?2");
        pictureBox3.Load("http://i.imgur.com/ZkWyBo5.jpg?2");
    }
```

Your code was hanging because of not correct use of the using statement. Keep in mind that in a using statement that there is a scope.

If you want to use your code:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var request1 = WebRequest.Create("http://i.imgur.com/ZkWyBo5.jpg?2");
        var request2 = WebRequest.Create("http://i.imgur.com/ZkWyBo5.jpg?2");
        var request3 = WebRequest.Create("http://i.imgur.com/ZkWyBo5.jpg?2");

        using (var response1 = request1.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var stream1 = response1.GetResponseStream())
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = Bitmap.FromStream(stream1);
            }
        }
        using (var response2 = request2.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var stream2 = response2.GetResponseStream())
            {
                pictureBox2.Image = Bitmap.FromStream(stream2);
            }
        }
        using (var response3 = request3.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var stream3 = response3.GetResponseStream())
            {
                pictureBox3.Image = Bitmap.FromStream(stream3);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, Done it. Thank you. @WagoL